# Apply CSS to TR if certain style is in a TD

Tags: javascript, jquery

As title says, need to `addclass()` to a `tr` (the `tr`, if multiple) if the `td` has a certain class.

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="scratched">Test</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="scratched">Test</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So if the td has class "scratched", apply class "line" to the tr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) filter:

```
$('tr').has('td.scratched').addClass('line');
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaGk/) for example.

Comment: I swear i tried that! but i thought it did every row.. worked awesome. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of:

```
$('td.scratched').parent().addClass('line');
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.parent()` like

```
$('td.scratched').parent('tr').addClass('line');
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4zuG6/)